# Fabric JS move image inside the image container

Tags: fabricjs

I need a functionality where i need to be able to position image properly inside the frame of the image itself.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the image container will be of a fixed size, and if the image is bigger than the frame itself, I need to be able to reposition image inside the frame. I tried clipping the image with a rectangle and positioning the image inside the rectangle but the clip creates a new image equal to the size of the rectangle so it has not worked so far. Is there any property in the `fabric.Image` class that lets us move image position inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Fabric.js v2, image cropping can be done using a combination of four properties: `width`, `height`, `cropX`, and `cropY`. (http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes#image)

As an example, an image with native dimensions of 500x500 pixels can be center cropped to 300x300 pixels like this:

```
img.set({
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  cropX: 100,
  cropY: 100
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This seems to be what i wanted, but i am facing one for problem. So i upload an image first, then later i replace the image. How do i fit the new image properly in the old image's size? suppose my old image was 200*300 and my new image is 300*500, when i replace the src, and set the width & height to 200*300, the new image is cropped. Rather i want the new image to fit inside the old frame. How do i do that? Thanks you so much for helping

Comment: You'll need to compare the ratio of the new image to the ratio of the container, then crop the larger dimension accordingly. Feel free to open a new question if you get stuck.